# Pass parameters to PHP from Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a calendar where users, after logging in, can select the day and hour for their appointment. Right now, the problem i'm having is that I don't know how to pass the selected day from the Fullcalendar app to PHP where the next booking step takes place.

These are the codes I'm working with:

Fullcalendar parameters

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid' ],
      defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
      selectable: true,
      locale: 'es',
      height: 500,
      longPressDelay: 500,
      dateClick: function(info) {
        $('#calendar-modal').modal('show');
      }
  });
            calendar.render();
  });

</script>
```

CSS popup that shows hours and then takes you to the next step in the booking process:

```
        <div id="calendar-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <form action="step.php?id=<?php foreach($result as $r): ?><?php echo $r['id']; ?><?php endforeach; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Pick your date</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <?php 
                            $calendar_hours = explode(',', $r['calendar_hours']);
                            foreach ($calendar_hours as $hours) {
                                echo '
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="radio" id="'.$hours.'" name="'.$hours.'" value="'.$hours.'" class="form-check-input">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="'.$hours.'">'.$hours.'</label>
                                </div>
                                ';
                            }
                        ?>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Book">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What am I missing? How can I solve this?

Comment: <form form action ...
Shouldn't it be just one "form" here?

Comment: @Pampy Sorry! Typo when pasting the code in here. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You should probably read more about HTTP and HTML forms to understand how everything works. In essence you have to add the date as an input to your form or send it to your backend via ajax.

Comment: 1) you should be using the `select` callback to choose dates in fullCalendar, not dateClick. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback . This allows the user to select a time period directly (if using the timegrid views) as well as just a date. 2) the selected date/time is provided in the `info` object which comes into that callback method (and the same in dateClick, while you're using that). So you need to then put that date somewhere into your modal form, by using Javascript.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks so much for your answer! It really helped me a lot. So I switched over to `select` and then used a jQuery selector to display the data in the modal. From here I can grab the date and `POST` it into the next PHP file. Thankfully I can take it from here now.

If possible, please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as as the correct answer.

Comment: Sure, I've done that below, thanks. Glad it was useful to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of points which will help you:

1) you should be using the `select` callback to choose dates in fullCalendar, not `dateClick`. See fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback for details. This allows the user to select a time period directly (if using the timegrid views) as well as just a date.

2) the selected date/time is provided in the `info` object which comes into that callback method (and the same in dateClick, while you're using that). So you need to then put that date somewhere into your modal form, by using Javascript.